# Dropdown menu stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have accordion menu on the left at my page. Today I noticed drastically decreasing visits, trying to find problem i found that my menu has stopped working 3 weeks ago. It used to drop down when i clicked on arrow, and when i click on menu that has sub-menu it remains open with highlight at parent menu. Now when i click products, my menu dont collapsing anymore. Tried to change classes and linking to newest version of jQuery but not worked.
Please help me with that, or what cause it to suddenly stopped working?

[My site with not working menu](http://wisbhp.pl/sprzet-ppoz/)

**Javascript**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#left li.menu-item-has-children').prepend('<span class="holder"></span>');
   $('#left li.menu-item-has-children > .holder').on('click', this, function(){
      var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
   });
 $('#left li.current-menu-item').addClass('open').children('ul').slideDown();
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.uslugi >a{
    color: #F00 !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
#left,
#left ul,
#left ul li,
#left ul li a {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #515151;
  margin:0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#left ul li a:hover{
color: #000;
background-color: rgba(47, 139, 182, 0.1);
}
.widget.widget_nav_menu li:before{
    display: none;
}

#main-wrapper .widget li:hover{
    background:none;
}
#left ul ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#left ul ul li a {
    cursor: pointer;
padding: 0 5px;
z-index: 1;
color: #344E83;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 98%, rgba(184,238,255,0.81) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(right top, left top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(98%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91)), color-stop(100%, rgba(184,238,255,0.81)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 98%, rgba(184,238,255,0.81) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 98%, rgba(184,238,255,0.81) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 98%, rgba(184,238,255,0.81) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 98%, rgba(184,238,255,0.81) 100%);
}
#left .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
     content: "";
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
margin: 10px 13px 0 0;
border-top: 6px solid #5F5F5F;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
    }
.holder{
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
padding: 11px 26px;
z-index: 8;
position: absolute;
margin: 1px -3px 0 0;
right: 0;
background: none;
    }
.holder:hover {
    background: rgba(47, 139, 182, 0.1);
}
#left ul li.open > a,
#left ul li.active > a,
#left ul ul li:hover > a,
#left ul ul li.open > a,
#left ul ul li.active > a,
.current-page-ancestor a {
color: #4686E6;
background-color: rgba(47, 139, 182, 0.2);
}
#left ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}

#left ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:979px){
        .span3{
        width:186px;
        margin-left:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the html? You mean the menu on the left, yeah?

Comment: Yes its on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is not working due to html markup problems (script tag) Check it out with firebug > script > inline at around line 444:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {`

etc.

You should close the script tag, then open a new one:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script><script>( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
....
</script>`

Comment: Thanks for attention, I've changed it before from separate blocks to one like You pointed it, but forgot to change it again. Now i did like u said, and it's still not working. When i click on product on the center of page, it highlights only the parent menu, but not collapsing like before..

Comment: try putting the <script> opening tag on a new line.

Comment: you have html markup issues, which is why the browser doesn't "see" the script... for all script tags and style tags you added check properly opening and closing them. Read the errors here: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwisbhp.pl%2Fsprzet-ppoz%2F

Comment: I'm talking about manually added scripts, styles etc. Also check that link tag. if you're sure they are all correct, then it may be an issue with autoptimize screwing things up

Answer (score 0):

It seems your selector doesn't have any match:

```
#left li.menu-item-has-children > .holder
```

I don't see your holder class within li.menu-item-has-children definition. And it looks like you should add a **holder** class to your `<a>` element.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: added static holder class to <a> but not working.
From what i remember it should add holder class to menu with childs:
$('#left li.menu-item-has-children').prepend('<span class="holder"></span>');

Comment: adding static will not work, the issue is the script not working period

Comment: Can you try to disable autoptimize plugin and see if it helps. Also try to check 
if $( document ).ready(function() {...} ) 
gets called

Comment: @yezzz yes that's true. It looks like the autoptimize plugins messes around.